# I turned off the electric fence too early, am I stuck?

Tags: borderlands-2

I'm stuck in the **[Shielded Favors](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Shielded_Favors)** quest in the Southern Shelf. I was doing a different quest, turned it off, finished said quest, and returned to this one. Claptrap told me to run through the fence, but it was already turned off. I'm stuck in this quest now.

Do I just ignore this quest or...?

Comment: It would help to know which quest we're talking about...  what area are you in, even?

Comment: Sorry sorry, typing a bit speedy here, but, hammar helped. gottit gottit.

Comment: @Rox If hammar's answer is right then you should upvote it and mark it as accepted (the up arrow and green checkmark to the left of his answer).

Comment: I remember doing this on my first playthrough. I ran ahead trying to explore as far as I can before I started doing quests. When I eventually got to this quest, I realized I already took out the generator but didn't pick up the fuse. Claptrap insisted I go through the barrier still. Leaving the area and returning back made the barrier reappear and you can go ahead and walk into it.

Comment: Running through the fence isn't an objective, it's just for comedic value.

Answer (score 7):

Shutting down the fence ahead of time is perfectly fine. You should be able to pick up the fuse you need near the porta potty.

[image: Location of the fuse]

Comment: Plus running through the electric is _not_ going to help anyways

Answer (score 0):

If you turned off the electric fence, wait for about half hour to an hour for it to reset or travel somewhere else and then go back. It will reset then.